# Selecting an unknown variable from a database using LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have created a search bar that searches for a specific key word in each paragraph on the page. Each paragraph has its own column in the table. When it searches the database I can't seem to select the one specific box.
This is what I have, I am using PHP to do it which is why the SQL is under a variable

```
$sql = "SELECT (???) FROM article WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR paraOne LIKE '%$search%' OR paraTwo LIKE '%$search%' OR paraThree LIKE '%$search%';";
```

As the information could be in any of the columns on the database I need to select the unknown cell instead of having to specify what column it should be in.

Comment: Normalize your database. Each paragraph should be a row, not a column.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `IF` to check each column and return it if it matches.

```
SELECT 
    IF(title LIKE '%$search%', title, NULL) AS title,
    IF(paraOne LIKE '%$search%', paraOne, NULL) AS paraOne,
    IF(paraTwo LIKE '%$search%', paraTwo, NULL) AS paraTwo,
    IF(paraThree LIKE '%$search%', paraThree, NULL) AS paraThree
FROM article 
WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR paraOne LIKE '%$search%' OR paraTwo LIKE '%$search%' OR paraThree LIKE '%$search%'
```

This will return all the columns that match the pattern; if a column doesn't match, it's returned as `NULL`.

Comment: This was close but it only got me the first result. Both paraOne and paraThree have the word I'm searching for but it'll only come up with paraOne. Do you know any way to get around that?? Thanks